# apache2 subdirectory access

Tags: apache, apache2, subdirectory

I am setting up an apache server on my linux (debian) machine.

I am making a website, with sub directories that contains my css and image file.

Here is my config.

```
<Directory /var/www/*>
    Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
    AllowOverride none
    Order allow,deny
    Allow from all
</Directory>
```

Is that configuration correct for access to sub directory

Answer (score 3):

You don't need the asterisk(*) after www.

```
<Directory /var/www/>
    Options -Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
    AllowOverride none
    Order allow,deny
    Allow from all
</Directory>
```

I'm not a huge fan of allowing indexes, so I disabled those and removed the asterisks. The above will deny indexes and grant allow access to any sub-directory of /var/www.

Comment: PS: Be sure to reload Apache after you update the files.